# Want to create a sparse matrix like dataframe from a dataframe in pandas/python

Tags: python, pandas, sparse-matrix

I have a data frame like this
[image: input data]

I want to convert it to something like this,note the ds is the day someone visited,and will have values from 0 to 31, for the days not visited it will show 0, and for the days visited it will show 1. It's kinda like sparse matrix,can someone help
[image: desired result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Update: `pd.get_dummies` now accepts `sparse=True` to create a `SparseArray` output.*

`pd.get_dummies(s: pd.Series)` can be used to create a one-hot encoding like such:

```
header = ["ds", "buyer_id", "email_address"]
data = [[23, 305, "fatin1bd@gmail.com"],
        [22, 307, "shovonbad@gmail.com"],
        [25, 411, "raisulk@gmail.com"],
        [22, 588, "saiful.sdp@hotmail.com"],
        [24, 664, "osman.dhk@gmail.com"]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=header)
df.join(pd.get_dummies(df["ds"]))
```

output:

```
ds  buyer_id    email_address   22  23  24  25
0   23  305     fatin1bd@gmail.com  0   1   0   0
1   22  307     shovonbad@gmail.com     1   0   0   0
2   25  411     raisulk@gmail.com   0   0   0   1
3   22  588     saiful.sdp@hotmail.com  1   0   0   0
4   24  664     osman.dhk@gmail.com     0   0   1   0
```

Just for added clarification: The resulting dataframe is still stored in a *dense* format. You could use `scipy.sparse` matrix formats to store it in a true sparse format.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the solution from @sim. By using the parameter columns, one can avoid the join.
the sparse=True parameter will return a sparse matrix. sparse=False will return a dense matrix.

```
header = ["ds", "buyer_id", "email_address"]
data = [[23, 305, "fatin1bd@gmail.com"],
        [22, 307, "shovonbad@gmail.com"],
        [25, 411, "raisulk@gmail.com"],
        [22, 588, "saiful.sdp@hotmail.com"],
        [24, 664, "osman.dhk@gmail.com"]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=header)
df=pd.get_dummies(df,columns=['ds'],sparse=True)
```

If you use sparse=True, the result can be converted back to dense using sparse.to_dense()
 on the specific column. For more details refer to [User Guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/sparse.html)

```
ds_cols=[col for col in df.columns if col.startswith('ds_')]
df=pd.concat([df[['buyer_id',"email_address"]],
                           df[ds_cols].sparse.to_dense()],axis=1)
```